# Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'float'>"})

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, text-classification

For text classification, i wanted to use CNN. The resource is https://github.com/kk7nc/Text_Classification/blob/master/code/CNN.py

I uploaded my data. Example for the content of the csv data file is:

text,label

'this is the first document',1

'this document is the second document',2

The first element in rows is text, last element is the class of the text.

When I fit my data to the model:

```
X_train_Glove,X_test_Glove, word_index,embeddings_index = loadData_Tokenizer(X_train,X_test)


model_CNN = Build_Model_CNN_Text(word_index,embeddings_index, 17) # 17 classes in my data


model_CNN.summary()

model_CNN.fit(X_train_Glove, y_train,
                              validation_data=(X_test_Glove, y_test),
                              epochs=1000,
                              batch_size=128,
                              verbose=2)

predicted = model_CNN.predict(X_test_Glove)

predicted = np.argmax(predicted, axis=1)


print(metrics.classification_report(y_test, predicted))
```

Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'float'>"})

How can I fix this?

Comment: you have to produce a **minimal** reproducible example, not the whole codebase

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same case

## Fitting the ANN to the Training set

model.fit(X_train, y_train ,batch_size = 20, epochs = 50, verbose=1)

ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, (<class 'list'> containing values of types {'(<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'float'>"})'})

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help, then update your answer with code explanations and improved formatting. It will help others understand.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the question.

In my experience model.fit works while x_train and y_train have the same type, i.e. both arrays or both lists. Thus, use the same datatype in both arguments.